# How to find inverse function in Wolfram Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

The question seems too easy to answer, however it is not, since I have to deal with functions that do not have closed forms (or I don't know how to find them). For example, I would like to find inverse functions for:
   y == x Tan[x]
and
   y == a x + b Tan[x].

Thus far, I used Newton-Rhapson's method for the inverse transformations. It works fine, but requires iterations. I just wonder whether there is a method to prove that there is a better solution or not. I've tried Wolfram Mathematica to find a solution, but since I'm a beginner. I have had no luck to get anything meaningful.

Comment: You should try http://math.stackexchange.com/ or http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/. Stackoverflow seems to be the wrong place for such a question.

Comment: You might be interested in [this theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem).

Comment: Thank you all. I have solved the problem using the Fit method. The resulting polynomial coefficients have to be calculated just once and then using Horner's scheme gives a real speed boost.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it can't be done.

```
Solve[y == x Tan[x], x]
```

> Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.

```
InverseFunction[# Tan[#] &]
```

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. Such functions don't have inverse ones in closed forms. I did exactly the same before posting this question. Maybe I should try to make an approximation of the inverse functions and check their error bounds. Newton-Rhapson method works fine, but it is too slow. I need to make it computationally efficient (in C/C++, CUDA or OpenCL).